# Image on top of mail displaying extra space to top in outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I'm creating a HTML Email and it works fine across most clients. My design is reliant on the Image the Mail starts with. It needs to be on the very top. In Outlook however the Mail displays a Border around the whole Mail. On top its like 20px and on the sides about 10px. Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Web Font / @font-face : BEGIN -->
    <!--[if mso]>
        <style>
            * {font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif !important;}
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!-- Web Font / @font-face : END -->

    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin:0 !important;
        }
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            Margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto; 
        }
        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }
        .yshortcuts a {
            border-bottom: none !important;
        }
        .mobile-link--footer a,
        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color:inherit !important;
            text-decoration: underline !important;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }
        .button-td:hover,
        .button-a:hover {
            background: #555555 !important;
            border-color: #555555 !important;
        }
        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid,
            .fluid-centered {
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                Margin-left: auto !important;
                Margin-right: auto !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .fluid-centered {
                Margin-left: auto !important;
                Margin-right: auto !important;
            }
            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }
            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                Margin-left: auto !important;
                Margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body width="100%" bgcolor="28bffe" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<div style="background-color:#28bffe;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" size="100%,35%" src="images/bg.jpg" color="#28bffe"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
    <table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <tr><td valign="top" align="left" background="images/bg.jpg" style="background-size: 100% auto; background-repeat: no-repeat; ">
        <center style="width: 100%;">

            <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
            <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;">
                Title
            </div>
            <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END -->

            <!-- Main Body Container for Snippets: Begin -->
            <div style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
                <tr>
                <td>
                <![endif]-->
                <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">

                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; margin:0; padding: 0; line-height: 0; font-size: 0;">
                                <img src="images/hero.gif" width="600" height="" alt="Whoop" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;outline:none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; margin:0; padding: 0;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 25px 0; text-align: center; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 23px; color: #000000; font-weight:normal;">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatiopbus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <img src="images/slogan.png" width="600" height="" alt="Whoop" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;outline:none;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                <!-- Email Body : END -->
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
            </div>
            <!-- Main Body Container for Snippets: END -->



            <!-- Main Body Container for Snippets: Begin -->
            <div style=" margin: auto;">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
                <tr>
                <td>
                <![endif]-->
                <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="" width="100%" >

                    <tr style="background-color: #1a1a1a;">
                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <img src="images/pier.jpg" width="276" height="" alt="Whoop" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 276px;outline:none; padding: 10px 0;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr style="background-color: #1a1a1a;">
                        <td style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 15px; font-weight:normal;">
                            <br><webversion style="text-decoration: none; color: #8a8a8a;">WEBVERSION LINK</webversion><br>
                            <br><unsubscribe style="text-decoration: none; color: #8a8a8a;">UNSUB LINK</unsubscribe><br><br><br><br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                <!-- Email Body : END -->
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
            </div>
            <!-- Main Body Container for Snippets: END -->


        </center>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Does anyone know about this problem and know how to fix this? The Problem is in Outlook 2007,10,11.

Answer (score 1):

It might help somebody, I had the same issue, I solved it by applying an inline style to the image with:

```
style="display: block;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the facilities to test this at the moment, but I'd try setting both the **body and table** tags to have a style of:

```
style="margin: 0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;"
```

To give the various versions of Outlook the best chance at rendering it properly.

If you're able to post the complete code (or a reduced version which still has the problem) then it'd be easier to test.

Comment: Thank you, I tried magin: 0; and padding:  0; in various places. 
The Newsletter isn't that long, so I included the whole thing. Do you have the same problem in general too? I have it in all my Emails, wich wasn't a big deal, since in most mails, the background img isn't that important. But this Email I'm combinding the heroimg with the background, so the positioning is very important.